# What configuration is required to use date_views with a field?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have a custom entity "referral" which is available for views:

```
function mymodule_entity_info() {
  return array(
    'referral' => array(
      'label' => t('Referral'),
      'controller class' => 'EntityAPIController',
      'views controller class' => 'EntityDefaultViewsController',
      ...
    ),
  );
}
```

The `mymodule_referral` table has a field `referred_at` which is a timestamp (stored as an int); I'd like to add a filter on this field to my view. I've got it displaying and filtering correctly with `hook_views_data_alter` and `views_handler_*_date`, but I'd prefer popup date selectors.

I understand that the `date_views` submodule of `date` should do what I want, but I can't find proper documentation on how to use it.

```
function mymodule_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  ...
  $data['mymodule_referral']['referred_at']['filter'] = array(
    'real field' => 'referred_at',
    'handler' => 'date_views_filter_handler',
  );
}
```

doesn't seem to be sufficient, because it displays in the view edit page as

```
FILTER CRITERIA

    Referral: Referred_at (Missing date fields!) | Settings
```

If I open the settings there's a compulsory field

```
DATE FIELD(S) *
Select date field(s) to filter.
```

with no options to select.

The [only reference I can find to the "Missing date fields!" error message](https://drupal.org/node/320596) talks about `hook_date_api_fields`, but that hook doesn't seem to exist in 7.

What configuration am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to mapping `'handler'` to `'date_views_filter_handler'` you need to tell `date_views` that the field is a date:

```
function mymodule_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  ...
  $data['mymodule_referral']['referred_at']['filter'] = array(
    'handler' => 'date_views_filter_handler',
    'is date' => TRUE,
  );
}
```

In the filter settings for `referred_at` you will now see `referred_at` as an option for "DATE FIELD(S)", and if you select it then it will work as expected.